# sum rows in dataframe based on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

How can I merge rows in the given dataframe as shown below? For each account and currency, I have to sum the values, so that there's no division by sector.

[image]

Comment: I would look into `pd.dataframe.groupby()` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
df.groupby(['acccount','currency'])['sum'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: I see, every answer is correct. But this one is the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

I will do a groupby operation on 'account','currency' and apply sum method on the sum column:

```
df.groupby(by=['account','currency'])['sum'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid groupby here by setting `account` and `currency` as index and then take sum using `pd.Series.sum` which has parameter `level`

```py
df.set_index(['account','currency'])['sum'].sum(level=[0, 1]).reset_index()
```